# How to properly make default SSL VirtualHost with apache2?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https

I have an Ubuntu server with apache2 serving the 2 different domains `example.com` and `test.net` with valid SSL certificates. I set up VirtualHosts on port 443 to serve my SSL secured domains and on port 80 to redirect to https.

Now I had the problem, that the company I rented the vServer from has a domain `id.provider.com` pointing to the vServers IP address and my logs and mails are flooded with errors, because webcrawlers accessing this `id.provider.com` domain.

So I want a fallback Virtual Host just dropping the connection, if the server receives a request matching neither of my domains. For unsecured http requests on port 80 I already achieved this, but I have problems doing the same on port 443 for secured https requests.

I set up a fallback VirtualHost file on 443 as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/default_access.log combined

                <Location />
                        <RequireAny>
                                Require all denied
                        </RequireAny>
                </Location>

                SecRuleEngine On
                SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "403" "phase:4,id:1,drop"
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But when I ensite this config I can't neither access `https:example.com`, `https://test.net` nor `https://id.provider.com` anymore. Firefox, Chrome and Edge just say that an SSL protocol error occured. If I dissite this config `https:example.com` and `https://test.net` work fine, but I have the webcrawler errors again. I wouldn't mind if the fallback renders an error as long as the other hosts work fine. How do I have to configure this fallback, so that it doesn't stop my other hosts from working? I think this happens because the fallback doesn't have a trust chain to establish a secured connection, but how shall I serve a certificate for a domain I do not own? Also I can't setup a certificate for any domain someone would stupidly point at my server.

I know, I could also turn this warnings off, but it bothers me, that someone would land on 'my website' by entering a completely unrelated URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enable `SSLEngine On` on *all* vhosts for port 443. Even for the fallback one here.

Since you want to reject all visitors anyway, you don't really *need* a valid certificate, so just use whatever you happen to have available – you could even generate a self-signed one for `goaway.invalid` or some other arbitrary domain. There's no practical difference whether the unwanted visitors successfully reach your 403 error page, or whether they abort due to unacceptable certificate.